# Jquery form validation submit handler not working

Tags: jquery, forms, jquery-validate

I have an existing application which uses JavaScript to do form validation and im trying to replace it with jQuery. My form has up to 20 fields and i am trying to validate only one field for now.

This is the jQuery function i wrote to validate one field.

```
$(function() {

 //$(".submit").click(function(){
//   alert("jq");
     $( "#serviceRtpLogMainForm" ).validate({
         rules: {
             p_incdate_in: "required"
                },
         messages: {
             p_incdate_in: "Please enter the inception date."
                },
         submitHandler: function(form) {
                    // do other things for a valid form
                    form.submit();
                 }

 //});
});
```

And below is how the form, submit and the field in question is being validated.

```
<html:form action="/serviceRtpLogMain"  styleId="serviceRtpLogMainForm">

<html:text name = "serviceRptLog" property="p_incdate_in" styleId="incidDate" onfocus="cancelRequest1('DATE')" />
           <A href="javascript:cal4.popup();">
```

```
<td valign="middle" align="left" width="100%" colspan="4" height=38  class="td3" >
         <input type=submit value=Submit class="submit">
         <input type=reset value=Reset> 
     </td>
```

Not my aim is to just validate if the field has been filled and to submit the form only if the field has been filled in the right format.

What am i doing wrong here?

Comment: I have a debug point at  $( "#serviceRtpLogMainForm" ).validate in firefox developer tools. It dosent even go there.. which confuses me a little more.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Make sure that your html will be like the below,

```
<form id="serviceRtpLogMainForm" action="/serviceRtpLogMain">
    <td valign="middle" align="left" width="100%" colspan="4" height="38"  class="td3" >
        <input type="text" name="p_incdate_in" class="p_incdate_in"/>
        <input type="submit" value="Submit" class="submit"/>
     </td>
</form>
```

and Script is

```
$(function() {        

    $( "#serviceRtpLogMainForm" ).validate({
        rules: {
                p_incdate_in: "required"
                },
        messages: {
                 p_incdate_in: "Please enter the inception date."
                 },
        submitHandler: function(form) {
                            // do other things for a valid form
                            form.submit();
                         }

        });

      });
```

Check the [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bNT5P/1)

or
      If you dont want to use name attribute, add class attribute to your element and add rules like below,

```
       $( "#serviceRtpLogMainForm" ).validate({            
          submitHandler: function(form) {
                            // do other things for a valid form
                            form.submit();
                         }

        });
        $(".p_incdate_in").rules("add", { 
                    required:true,  
                    messages:"Please enter the inception date."
         });
```

Check [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sesubash/bNT5P/2/)

Comment: @Subhash the name attribute for my form field is already taken. Can i use styleId instead?

Comment: and im surprised as to why on clicking the submit button, the debug point is not reached in firefox developer tools

Comment: got it buddy.. i am able to validate the required fields. thanks